# PHP check if array index in variable has a value | isset() always returning true

Tags: php, arrays

I have an variable called `$vars` which contains an array that is submitted with form:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Sample Name
    [email] => test@test.com
    [job_role] => 
    [telephone_number] => telephone number
    [comment] => comment
)
```

**How can I check if `job_role` index is containing a value?**

---

I tried:

```
if (in_array('', $vars)){
  echo "Job role can't be empty";
} else {
  echo "Job role submitted";
}
```

But this works on the whole array and not only the `job_role` index.

Also, I tried:

```
if (isset($vars['job_role'])){
  echo "match found";
} else {
  echo "nothing there";
}
```

But it was returning "match found" even when I didn't submit anything...

**Why is `isset()` always returning true?**

Comment: ehemmm... why downvote?

Comment: The answer to the question "can anyone help" is "yes", but it is probably not the question you actually want to ask. Questions here benefit from being focussed and specific.

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: Can you tell me why the `isset` method in my code didn't work?... I found few question on here, and they all used it but it didn't work for me that's why I posted the question... I see people really didn't like it... By "can anyone help" I meant, why is my code not doing what I expected it to do... Sorry if I didn't word it properly.

Comment: @BareFeet `isset()` checks if the value defined (is set), not it is empty. In your code `$vars['job_role']` is probably an empty string, so, it's defined, but it's empty.

Comment: @halfer I'm sorry for making you an effort to edit my question again. The reason why I asked "Can anyone help" was just because I wanted to be polite. After reading the meta post, I understand why I should not do it. I will keep this in mind. Thank you. Also, I reworded my question to make it more clear what I was asking. I hope someone will take it positively now :)

Comment: Looks good to me, let us know if the duplicate link doesn't answer it. Yes, we prefer a technical style of writing here, where possible.

Comment: It partly answer my question. It explained how to check if the item in array is empty, however, it didn't explain why `isset()` was returning true. I now know, that it was returning an empty string which was considered as value even tho it was empty. I got an answer here and not in the question marked as duplicate. Something silly that could be easily mist by a beginner. Anyway, I got my answer! Thank you for your interest and few lessons ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`empty()`](https://php.net/empty) to check if the entry is not empty:

```
if (empty($vars['job_role'])) {
    echo "Job role can't be empty";
} else {
    echo "Job role submitted";
}
```

Because  `isset()` checks if the value defined (is set), not it is empty. In your code `$vars['job_role']` is probably an empty string, so, it's defined, but it's empty.